# Why in postgres default indexing is on b tree and not B+ tree

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree

What I have seen so far in the documentation of Postgres that when we want to index some column, it will by default use B tree as the data structure of indexing but B+ tree is much faster than B tree so why default indexing is on B tree and not on B+ tree.

For Reference(how B+ tree is better): https://www.tutorialcup.com/dbms/b-tree.htm

So my question is: why they are not using B+ tree for indexing by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the subject, but there seems to be nothing to gain using B+ trees instead of regular B trees for indexing in PostgreSQL.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AB%2B_tree#PostgreSQL's_use_of_B+_trees):

> Normal ("btree" type) indexes in Postgres are not B+ trees. The distinction between B+ trees and B-trees is kind of nonsense for database indexes in the first place -- all the columns in the index itself *are* the lookup key, and they're the same on the leaf level as any other level. The *record* itself is generally stored in a separate structure -- in the case of Postgres, it's the table heap.